# Wrist watch that is scratch-safe for typing on a laptop?

Tags: laptop

If a wear a typical wrist watch while typing on the laptop, then its buckle scratches the surface of my laptop. Is there a type of watch that is more friendly for that?

Answer (score 2):

Velcro watch bands won't cause damage to plastic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reference on instructables -- [Fabric watch-strap cover](http://www.instructables.com/id/Fabric-watch-strap-cover/)

[image]

It is for metal sensitive skin but would work nicely for your case too.
<sup>I gave up wearing the watch some years back; there is always one handy (laptop/cellphone/etc).</sup>